# Can ReportLab PDF 1.4 hyperlinks be made more size-efficient?

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, reportlab

I am adding HTTP links to text in ReportLab generated PDFs using canvas.linkURL(). With a 100 page document, there are approximately 10 on each page, so 1000 links overall.

All works well, but the size of the file on disk blows up when the links are included - from around 100KB to over 1MB.

Inspecting the PDF, there are structures for the links "% 'Annot.NUMBER38': class PDFDictionary" with matching structures "% 'R1351': class PDFStream" referenced from each link's /Contents.

Pulling the data from the PDF shows there is approx 0.4MB of the 'Annot.NUMBERnn' and 0.6MB of the PDFStream objects.

Following some experiments with http://code.google.com/p/pdfsizeopt/, I was typically able to reduce the size of PDFs by more than 50%. The key step which seems to achieve this is conversion from PDF 1.4 to 1.5. Might this suggest that PDF 1.4 is particularly inefficient at creating http:// hyperlinks?

For various reasons I need to continue to generate PDF 1.4 (primarily PDF/A-1).

Is this an fundamental issue with the PDF format itself, or is it possible to create hyperlinks in a more efficient way?

Comment: Is ReportLab able to produce PDF/A files? I looked it up and didn't find anything

Comment: I patched it myself to add PDF/A - I want to submit that to ReportLab but the code is very specific to what I need and not of great generic quality.